# Play Framework - Variables in URL instead of as ? parameters

Tags: url, routes, playframework-2.0

I'm a just starting to learn Play, so this is a basic question, but I've searched every term I can think of and can't find the answer.

All I want to do is have a page that on submit takes an ID from a text field and puts it in the URL directly (e.g. /myservice/person/123).  Instead, the URL being generated contains the ID as a parameter (e.g. /myservice/person?id=123).

I know my controller is being invoked correctly if I type the URL in by hand, so I'm inclined to think my routes file is correct.  This is what my entry looks like:

```
GET   /person/:id    controllers.PersonActions.getPerson(id: String)
```

So I'm assuming something is going wrong in my template, which looks like this:

```
@form(routes.PersonActions.getPerson(personID)) {
    @* @inputText(personForm("id")) *@
    <input type="text" name="id" value="@personID">
    <input type="submit" value="Get">
}
```

You can see that I've commented out another way using @inputText also, but it behaves identically for me.  I'm not tied to either method.

I've also tried this using POST, which removes the ID from the URL entirely, which I don't understand either, but since I'm just doing a simple query, I'd rather use GET.

Can anyone help me understand what's going on here?  I feel like there's something fundamental about how routing/URLgeneration works that I'm not understanding, but I've gone through the tutorial and the docs so many times today I'm at a loss.

Thanks in advance.

Oh, and I'm using Java 7, Play 2.1, and Eclipse Kepler

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to skip a step and map form request data from a view directly to a controller method.  You will need to submit the form, have a controller parse the data and then render the next appropriate view based on the data you parsed from the form.

Remember that the personId in your view is a parameter that is bound server-side when the view is rendered. In this case, the submit url of the form is hard coded to whatever personId is passed in to the view at render time -- it doesn't change dynamically when the input box changes.

To fix, add a controller method to accept requests from `/person` (I'm guessing this based on the part in your question that says the form is being submitted to `/person?id=123`, in any case it should be the URL of the form you've shown above)

e.g. if you want to use a GET method for the form add:

```
GET     /person     controllers.PersonActions.findPerson(id: String)
```

and in your PersonActions controller (I'm assuming you're using Java, if scala I'm sure you can adapt it from the docs)

```
public static Result findPerson(String id){
    /*
     * I'm assuming this method exists and works because you say 
     * when you type in /person/123 manually the routing works 
     * and your router says getPerson is the method name for that URL.
     */
    return getPerson(id);
}
```

Comment: Wait, if it is possible, you could try changing the route I have to directly point to your getPerson method, e.g. `GET  /person    controllers.PersonActions.getPerson(id:String)` If that works it leaves you with one less controller method to maintain.  I'm not sure if it is possible to point multiple urls to the same controller method -- I think it would mean the reverse router would be non-deterministic for that url.  It is probably worth a try.

Comment: I think the advice given in the answer is sound. If you're submitting a GET request from a form, field values from the form are going to appear on the URL as query parameters. That's just the way that forms work. Having the `find` action should look up the ID and then either returning a 404 response or redirecting to the `get` action is the approach I would take. This gives the OP the wikipedia-style search behaviour that it seems they're looking for (the ID lookup goes straight to the person if the ID exists).